# CakePhp não carrega Css, JavaScript e imagens

Tags: css, cakephp, apache, centos

Estou com CakePHP na versão 1.3.15 instalado num servidor CentOs e o mesmo projeto que funciona na internet, no servidor local só carrega texto e mais nada.
Como eu habilite o modo desenvolvedor, se tivesse algum erro, ele iria carregar.
Acredito que o erro deve estar no caminho do css.

[image: httpd.conf]

Comment: Verifica se o `.htaccess` esta na pasta raiz

Comment: @JefersonAssis, vc diz o .htaccess do cake, correto?

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Pode ser que seu apache não esteja configurado para ler o `.htaccess` ou o  modo `rewrite` está desativado. Se estiver usando o `wamp` é muito comum acontecer :ṕ

Comment: @WallaceMaxters.
Estou usando CentOs 6.7 modo texto. 
Pelo que eu vi o apache está correto. Vc teria alguma coisa para verificar no apache?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters. Pelo que eu vi, eu não tenho .htacess no CentOs a não ser o do cakephp.

Comment: @fabricio_wm faz um teste. Tira o `IfModule`. Se der pau, então o mod_rewrite  não está habilitado :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters  
Eu usei o vi para verificar o arquivo httpd.conf que está dentro do diretório /etc/httpd/conf/
Ao verificar estava AllowOverride All
Eu não consegui verificar o .htacess pq é como se ele estive inacessível.

Comment: @coloquei a imagem no final da pergunta.
Vê se isso ajuda.

Comment: o que quer dizer com “htaccess inacessível”?

Comment: Estou usando o CentOs via virtualbox como eu disse anteriormente. Ao enviar via ssh, pergunta se eu desejo substituir. ao dar um ls na pasta que está o arquivo, ele não aparece como se estivesse oculto. 
Ao usar o Vi na tentativa de editar, acontece como se eu estivesse criando um arquivo novo, @DanielOmine